# Mobile view: Votes, Answers and Views are misaligned

Tags: bug, status-completed, mobile-web, design

I...don't think I can un-see this. The alignment of the text isn't consistent and I would've expected that it would be aligned center relative to each element.

Browsers used: Firefox mobile 66.0.b13, Brave Browser 1.0.82 (Chromium 72.0.3626.105)

[image]

Comment: -1, not enough Eeeeek!

Comment: Surely I deserve *accolades* for finding a way to draw a freehand red circle on *mobile*. :)

Comment: @Makoto I made you this badge ⭕

Comment: @CodyGray It should be Eeₑₑek! in this case.

Comment: It seems Stacks might not be all it's cracked up to be.

Comment: Caused by `.narrow .status { ... border: 1px solid transparent; ... }` and by `.answered, .answered-accepted { border: 1px solid transparent; }`

Comment: @wizzwizz4 This isn't using Stacks.

Comment: @AaronShekey Oh. (checks source code) In which case I change my comment to "bring on Stacks".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A fix for this has merged and will go live in the next build, whenever that is. Thanks for reporting it!

I wasn't actually able to reproduce the misalignment on the questions with 0 answers. I *was* able to fix the alignment on questions with answers and accepted answers by adding a `margin-top: -1px` to compensate for that transparent border.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the purpose of the transparent border?